# Two different excel file to match their rows having same name

Tags: python, pandas

Using python pandas,

I am trying to write a condition in pandas which will match two columns from two different excel file having the same column name and different numerical values in them. For each column there are 2000 rows to match.

The condition:

- if final value = ( if File1(column1value) - File2(column1value) = 0 then update the value with 1;
- if File1(column1value) - File2(column1value) is less than or equ al to 0.2 then keep File1Column1Value;
- if (File1Column1) - File2(column1value) greater than 0.2 the. update the value with 0.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nx3WA.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
    df1 = pd.read_excel('file_name1') # get input from excel files
    df2 = pd.read_excel('file_name2')
    p1 = df1['p1'].values
    p11 = df2['p11'].values
    new_col = [] # we will store desired values here
    for i in range(len(p1)):
       if p1[i] - p11[i] == 0:
          new_col.append(1)
       elif abs(p1[i] - p11[i]) > 0.2:
          new_col.append(0)
       else:
          new_col.append(p1[i])
    df1['new_column'] = new_col # we add new column with our values
```

You can also remove old column `df.drop('column', axis = 1)`

Comment: The approach to iterating through the dataframe is not correct in Pandas, it should be done in a vectorized manner. Also, I'm pretty sure `new_col.append(df1['column'])` isn't what you intended, that appends all of the values.

Comment: @roganjosh, right, I missed index [i]. This was the best solution that came to my mind, I am sure it can be done in other ways

Comment: @Ach113 it's not working :/ can you check the image i attached?

Comment: @Sinbad, judging from the image, I think you need to take absolute value of the subtraction abs( a - b ). Also unlike your description ,the column names, where the values are stored are not identical, its P1 in one case and P11 in another.

Comment: @Arch113 i used the abs value and yes the column name are not same, sorry for that - the thing is actually the F1-F10 these are features for Patient 1 and other P2, P11 now what should i do to make  the code to work properly? I hope you got the idea from the image , i really need help here solving the issue :/

Comment: @Sinbad I have modified my 'solution'. If that does not work then I dont know what else can be done